# How do you send data from Excel to SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Here is the setup: there is one administrator with a master model, which is an Excel file that sits on his desktop. The model is composed of 10 parts which sit on SharePoint separately, and each part is owned by a 'user' who only sees his part on SharePoint and updates the part directly on SharePoint occasionally. Each part is linked to the master model so that when the administrator clicks 'data refresh' on the master model (in Excel on this desktop), it pulls in the new data from SharePoint and inputs it into Excel model.

How can it be set up so that instead of the user editing the sheet directly on SharePoint, the user can just edit in an Excel file on his desktop and then somehow have that be saved in SharePoint? And then I want the administrator to be able to pull information from all 10 parts all at once into his master Excel model.

I suppose SharePoint would serve as a sort of data repository in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've seen similar to what I think you are trying to do is when you have a Custom List and export it as an Excel file to your desktop. This file in your desktop remains connected to SharePoint and any update you make in your desktop, you can "refresh data" with SharePoint. In order to allow other user to keep a "copy" in their desktop that would update also SharePoint from their desktop, you can "Export Connection File" (DATA tab > Connections > Properties > Definition tan > Export Connection File) in Excel and this would create a file with ".odc" extension. This file can be shared with the other user that would be updating the Custom List using excel. I'm not a SharePoint expert, but I hope this helps